# Wrong username displayed in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459716/sharepoint-2007-how-to-set-column-level-permission/1470610#1470610), user [176392](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176392) has the name `dotnetworld`. In their comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459716/sharepoint-2007-how-to-set-column-level-permission/1470610#1470610) they have the username `technorati.com/people/technorati`.

The username on the comment does not match their current name. This shouldn't be a caching issue as they were last seen 8 hours ago (at time of writing).

Comment: OK; I'm confused... it is by design to show the username differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a problem, because the user hasn't specified a name in his user page. Maybe he logged in using different email accounts for the question and the comment. Not sure, if it is possible to fix that.

Comment: In addition it seems like the name is based on where they logged in from.

Answer (score 3):

I've edited the user's profile to achieve consistency - but yes, looks like a bug.

Comment: How do you know that this behaviour isn't normal and that everything else isn't the bug?!

Comment: @Welbog: you are a bug.

Comment: @voyager: You gave the Star Trek franchise a bad name.

Comment: @Welbog: touché.